# Cannot cast <Object, Map<Object, Object>> Map into more specific typed Map

Tags: java, object, dictionary, casting

I'm trying to cast a Map like this :

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> map = 
                 (HashMap<Integer, Map<String, String>>) pMap;
```

pMap is typed :

```
Map<Object, Map<Object, Object>> pMap
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I'm curious to know why, and also if it's possible to avoid the problem.

Comment: If you are sure that the key of pMap is an integer, then you can use the following type for pMap....Map<Integer, Map<Object, Object>> pMap

Comment: Well that's the problem, sometimes I would use String instead of Integer as a key.

Comment: Then you can declare the Key of 'map' also as Object, and perform the casting while operating on the key or the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because even though `Integer` is a subtype of `Object`, `Map<Integer, Integer>` is *not* a subtype of `Map<Object, Object>`.

You simply cannot cast it that way.

This is explained further in the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).

Comment: Okay, thank you. I guess I have to find another elegant way to make it as generic as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much familiar with generic class but can you try Map<**?**, Map> map
after replacing Integer by  ? It will case your Integer easily and as you wrote above that this key can be string too so I hope it will work for you.

Comment: I tried with `?` instead of `Object` but it's the same, the cast is forbidden. What I do is casting trough an iterator, I cannot directly cast the Map.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is what I did to avoid this problem :

I typed my Map like this :

```
Map<? super Object, ? super Object>
```

And it works, I can put whatever I want inside this Map. It can be :

```
Map<String, String>
```

or :

```
Map<Integer, Map<String, String>>
```

etc. It's the more flexible way I found. The only constraint is to cast the Map when I operate on the map (through `Iterator` or with `keySet`).

Hope it could help someone.